# Unity3d understanding positioning system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to instantiate an object (A) as a child of a canvas.
The position of A is set using a B object's position, also a child of the Canvas.

Not sure if this is useful for my question, but A and B both have a child.

When I spawn A, it's position is not  B's position at all, even if my `debug.log()` says so.

Here is what I have:

[image: http://prntscr.com/czz084]

Here is what the debug says:

[image: http://prntscr.com/czz0dt]

Here is the code:

```
 if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            GameObject Laser_Projectile = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Sprites/Object_Laser_Projectile") as GameObject);
            Laser_Projectile.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform, false);
            this.transform.localPosition = GameObject.Find("Player_Objects").transform.localPosition;
```

I tried to work with position and localPosition, no way to make it work.
I also tried to use the setParent argument (false or true), but setting it to true makes it even worst.

My question is: What I am missing, what am I not understanding? I never had this problem before.

Comment: If you're setting the object's parent, you should be able to set it's local position to `new Vector3(0,0,0)` and it will go onto its parent's position

Comment: I did that with the child of "Player_Objects", works well, but with "Player_Objects" itself... well, it's doing I don't know what ...

Comment: As Alfie says. "localPosition" means "my position relative to my parent". In other words, it doesn't matter where the parent is in the world (or within it's own parent), it's child's localPosition's VectorX.zero will be the vey middle of the parent. What you do is, you set the object's position to the same *numeric values* it's parent has, so you displace it. If parent is at 10, 10, and you set the child's localPosition to 10, 10 as well, the child will "globally" be at 20, 20 - as it was displaced by 10 units from it's parent's middle point.

Comment: Oh I see the issue, try this `Vector3 thePos = this.transform.parent.position - GameObject.Find("Player_Objects").transform.position;` and then set `this.transform.localPosition = thePos;`

Comment: It works, thanks for that, it's a bit tricky...
But I tried something else, and I still don't understand:
I have a canvas with an object as a child of it. I spawn an object as child of the canvas, I want it to be at the same position of the other child of the canvas, I set the new child the localPosition of the other child, but It's not at the same position, why that?

Comment: Okay that's great, I'll put it in an answer and explain it properly for you :)

Comment: Can you show me that code?

Comment: Yes I can.

  `GameObject Laser_Projectile = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Sprites/Object_Laser_Projectile") as GameObject);
            Laser_Projectile.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform, false);
          
  Vector3 thePos =  GameObject.Find("Player_Objects").transform.localPosition;
            Laser_Projectile.transform.localPosition = thePos;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the `localPosition` of the transform, this sets it relative to its parent, but you are setting it to an unrelated object's localPosition instead of its global position (`transform.position`), which will end up being incorrect. In this case, you can compare the parent's world position to the other object's world position like so

```
Vector3 thePos = this.transform.parent.position - GameObject.Find("Player_Objects").transform.position;
```

Then you can set the `localPosition` of the object using this new `Vector3`

```
this.transform.localPosition = thePos;
```